# Delete all entries from a custom record from UE Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a UE script that saves entry from a custom record into rejection reason on vendor bill. This part is working fine and this script is able to save the rejection reason to overcome the limitations of the Employee Centre users that do not have write access on vendor bill. However, since I am fairly new to scripting, I am not able to delete all the records from the custom record every time before the script executes. If someone could help me with the related code to delete all the existing records in the custom record, that would be great. I am adding my existing code for your reference.

```
/**
```

- @NApiVersion 2.x
- @NScriptType UserEventScript
- @NModuleScope SameAccount
  */
  define(['N/record'],

function(record) {

```
/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @param {Form} scriptContext.form - Current form
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) 
{

}

/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) 
{
    
}

/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function afterSubmit(scriptContext) 
{
// Get the value of the Reject reason
    var rejReason = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord165'    // Change this according to the internal id of the Field Reject Reason in the Custom Record Created
    });

    // Get the ID of the Vendor Bill Reject reason
    var venbillID = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord166'    // Change this according to the internal id of the Field Reject Reason in the Custom Record Created
    });

// populate the Reject Reason in the Vendor Bill Rejection Reason field
    var id = record.submitFields({
        type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
        id: venbillID,
        values: {
            custbody_rt_vendbill_rej_reason: rejReason //'testMSG01'
            //custrecord165: 'testMSG'//rejReason   // Change custbody1 to the internal id of the custom field Reject Reason in the Vendor Bill Record
        },
        options: {
            enableSourcing: false,
            ignoreMandatoryFields : true
        }
    });
}
return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit
};
```

});

Comment: Please clarify "delete all the records from the custom record every time before the script executes".  What records are you trying to delete (what's the record id)?  What is the custom record id (the custom record that is having records removed from it)?  What is the relationship between these two record types (i.e. is one a sublist to the other, or something else..)?

Comment: @Martha Sorry for not being clear, I wanted to delete all entries from the same custom record every time before creating a new entry. This is because once my script writes rejection reason from my custom record to vendor bill, there is no point keeping the data in the custom record anymore. I was hoping to either delete all previous records before the script starts or at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented such a requirement before. As I understand from your question, you need to delete all the entries from the custom record every time the script executes. This part can be added in the beginning of your code. Below is the sample code to help you with deleting all data from the custom record. In below snippet you need to replace "customrecord_tracker" with your custom record internal id and make other id changes as per your requirement

Please let me know how this goes for you! Happy coding! :)

```js
//Search on the custom record to get the all the results

var searchTracker = search.create({
            type: 'customrecord_tracker',
            filters: ['isinactive', search.Operator.IS,'F'],
            columns:['internalid']
            }); 
            var searchIcResults = searchTracker.run();
            log.debug('searchIcResults',searchIcResults);

//Get the range of 1000 search results, if your search results are going to be less than 999 then you need not change anything here
var jeSearch = searchIcResults.getRange({
                        start: 0,
                        end: 999
                    });

                    if (jeSearch && jeSearch.length > 0) {

                        for (var itr = 0; itr < jeSearch.length; itr++) {
                            var internalId = jeSearch[itr].getValue({
                                name: 'internalid'
                            });
                            
                var deleteCustRecord = record.delete({
                            type: 'customrecord_tracker', 
                            id: internalId
                            });
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: Thanks @anuradha, I will try this out and would let you know

Comment: @Rookie :Thanks sure, please mark my answer as correct if this works for you!